# Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode' from the text '鼠标'

Tags: c#, windows-8, app-store, microsoft-metro

Hey，I am just a new developer of windows 8 store app. Here is a question I met,even through I had tried my best to search the answers. But I can't find the solution.I hope there is someone could help me.

I just wanted to develop a test app on windows 8,but when I open the file "StandardStyle.xaml" which in the floder Common.The Visual Studio report the error:"Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode' from the text '鼠标'".

I am a  chinese,so the text is chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "StandardStyle.xaml", replace :

```
<ToolTipService.Placement>鼠标</ToolTipService.Placement>
```

With :

```
<ToolTipService.Placement>Mouse</ToolTipService.Placement>
```

ToolTipService.[Placement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.placementmode) can only be **Bottom**, **Left**, **Mouse**, **Right** or **Top**. It shouldn't have been auto-translated on Microsoft side. I had the same issue in French with the word `Souris` that I had to manually change to `Mouse`.

Comment: I've sloved this problem for you suggestiong.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`PlacementMode` is an enumeration (check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.placementmode). The text between the mark-ups is suppose to be replaced by a value.  So the only text valid are the one present in the link above.  Seems like globalisation is the problem here (translating things it should not).